# error 404 with Scrapy but not with urllib2

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrap the following website https://www.shopee.sg:

```
~$ scrapy shell https://www.shopee.sg
```

But I got a 404 error:

```
[s]   request    <GET https://www.shopee.sg>
[s]   response   <404 https://shopee.sg/>
```

While urllib2 can open this same url:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.shopee.sg')
print len(response.read())
```

shows:

```
78447
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the website examines user agent string and blocks Scrapy. If you set it to e.g. Chromium user agent string using `USER_AGENT`, it works:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36" "https://www.shopee.sg"
```